# How to set Charles to use TLS only

Tags: ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles 3.9.3 to develop a Flash application locally (that is normally embedded in a website). Recently, due to the POODLE issue, the upstream web server that hosts the website has changed the SSL setup it uses and no longer supports SSLv3.

Now it looks like Charles no longer can negotiate SSL with the upstream web server when I'm requesting URLs that are not part of my Flash application (all of these are forwarded to a local Apache server which still supports SSLv3). Instead I get this error message in the Charles logs:

```
SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I've looked in Charles settings dialog, but I can't find where to set Charles to use TLS instead of SSL. Any idea how to fix this?